# Implicitly convert generic classes

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to accomplish something like this.

```
public class GreatClass<A, B>
    where A : IA
    where B : IB, new()
{
    public void Function()
    {
        var list = new List<A>();
        var obj = new B { Items = list.ToArray() };
    }
}

public interface IA
{
}

public interface IB
{
    IA[] Items { get; set; }
}

namespace Namespace1 
{
    public class A : IA {}
    public class B : IB {}
}

namespace Namespace2
{
    public class A : IA {}
    public class B : IB {}
}
```

So I have two namespaces with similar classes which implements the same interface. I have some logic which I want to share between the classes in the two namespaces and am therefore using generic classes which implements the implemented interface.

However I get a compile error on "list.ToArray()" stating that it Cannot implicitly type 'A[]' to 'IA[]'. Is there something I can do which makes the compiler understand how to handle this?

Using .Cast() like a few of you have been suggesting gives me a runtime error instead. That I can't convert type IA[] to Namespace1.A[] (or Namespace2.A[]).

Comment: You can use `.Cast<IA>()` although since the array is empty you could just create an empty `IA[]` directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several options, but the best one is to strongly type your `B` class and make it generic.

This is the code that will do. Note that `TA` is the type of `A` you are passing in, thus always allowing to access the members strongly typed.

```
public interface IB<TA> where TA : IA
{
    TA[] Items { get; set; }
}
```

And change `GreaterClass` to this:

```
public class GreatClass<A, B>
    where A : IA
    where B : IB<A>, new()
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply declare your list like this:

```
var list = new List<IA>();
```

Comment: an explanation would be good? This is a good way of doing it though if it fits in with why the OP has that data structure, which is not clear from the question

Comment: I don't think that the "cast" approach is the right way if he can control the implementation. The array covariance works for reference types and in the inheritance hierarchy.

Comment: I think this is not a good way to do it, since you have to cast every time you want to expose an item from the list to the outside of the class.

Comment: It's how the `interface IB` is declared. If you want to expose an item of this array outside the class without using an interface, don't declare an array of interface, just declare this `A[] Items { get; set; }`.